# Piezzo buzzer schematics design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, piezo-buzzer

I've been having some issues with buzzer schematics pictured below.

Transistors have always been my weak spot and I currently don't have time to dive into it and just need this to work.

Quick what's what.

Buzzer is this one: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1808132343_Murata-Electronics-PKLCS1212E4001-R1_C113159.pdf part number is PKLCS1212E4001-R1.

BUZZER label is connected to a PWM output on a 3V3 IC pin.

VDD is connected to a Li-Ion battery (around 4V).

If I connect function generator directly to pins of the buzzer (F = 3kHz and Peak to peak voltage is 3V) I get a good sounding beep. As loud as I want it and everything is perfect.

If I instead place one lead of the function generator to BUZZER lable and the other to GND nothing happens but if I connect it from BUZZER to VDD all I get is a very faint beep that can hardly be heard.

Is there something wrong with schematics? I just need a sanity check.

Thank you so much!

[image: Buzzer schematics]

Comment: You might have damaged the 3.3 volt PWM output chip by connecting the function generator. It may have gone short circuit. Why did you do this - you must ask yourself.

Comment: Schematic is plausible… is you generator configured to put out 0 to 3V or -1.5 to 1.5V? in the second case you would bias in the wrong way the transistor and it could shut down the oscillation

Comment: @Andyaka While the board was powered, the chip was not outputing on the pin. I just placed func generator lead directly to the R6 resistor. Even if I damaged the chip that should not have an effect on the buzzer.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Thanks for info. I will have to check that, but I'm pretty sure that it's 0-3V because if I connect it directly to the buzzer it works fine.